# java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2, in a web service

Tags: android, web-services

I have a problem when trying to make a POST request to a webservice, review the structure of my method in my webservice and my Android method but I did not find the error.

this is my class of Android, my method is called:

> onClickUpdate (final int position, end String identifier)

```
public class tareasFragmento extends Fragment implements TareasAdapter.OnClickButton{

    private String url = "http://192.168.1.128:8080/WebServiceExamenFinal/webapi/tareas";
    private ArrayList<Tareas> listatarea = new ArrayList<>();


    //Si no funciona esto se puede borrar

    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    private List<Tareas> tareasList;
    private TareasAdapter tareasAdapter;
    private int assiId;

    public tareasFragmento() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tareas, container, false);


        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2,
                GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        final TareasAdapter adapter = new TareasAdapter(getActivity(), listatarea);
        adapter.setCallback(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        dialog.setMessage("Por favor espere...");
        dialog.show();
        try {
            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            deserializarJSONArray(response);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            if (dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                    "Error al realizar la petición\n" + error.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            if (dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"El error es: "+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return view;
    }

    public void deserializarJSONArray(JSONArray jsonArray) {

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Tareas tareas = new Tareas();
                tareas.setId(item.getString("id"));
                tareas.setNombreTarea(item.getString("nombreUsuario"));
                tareas.setEstudiante(item.getString("estudiante"));
                tareas.setNota(item.getString("nota"));

                listatarea.add(tareas);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error al procesar la respuesta de la petición: " + e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClickUpdate(final int position, final String identificador) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View MyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin_updatedonante, null);

        final EditText identidad = (EditText)MyView.findViewById(R.id.identificador_tarea);
        final EditText nombre_tarea = (EditText)MyView.findViewById(R.id.nombre_tarea);
        final EditText nota = (EditText)MyView.findViewById(R.id.nota_tarea);
        final EditText estudiante = (EditText)MyView.findViewById(R.id.estudiante_tarea);
        identidad.setEnabled(false);
        identidad.setText(identificador);

        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try{
            jsonObject.put("nombre_tarea","Ejemplo").put("nota","Ejemplo").put("estudiante", "Ejemplo");
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        builder.setView(MyView)
                .setPositiveButton("Registrar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        if(nombre_tarea.getText().toString().equals("") || nota.getText().toString().equals("") || estudiante.getText().toString().equals("")){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Porfavor llena todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                        }else{
                            String urlPut = "http://192.168.1.128:8080/WebServiceExamenFinal/webapi/tareas/";
                            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, urlPut + identificador, jsonObject,
                                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Se envió correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ocurrió un error al enviar la información", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });

                            queue.add(request);
                        }


                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No se actualizo ningun registro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClickDelete(final int position, final String identificador) {


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View MyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin_deletedonante, null);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)getView().findViewById(R.id.recycler_list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2,
                GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        final TareasAdapter adapter = new TareasAdapter(getActivity(), listatarea);
        adapter.setCallback(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        builder.setView(MyView)
                .setPositiveButton("Eliminar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"id: "+ identificador, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String urlDelete = "http://192.168.1.128:8080/WebServiceExamenFinal/webapi/tareas/";
                        final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
                        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.DELETE, urlDelete + identificador, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                //Aqui actualizo mi fragmento para que se vean reflejados los cambios, intete usar un notifysetDataChange pero no me
                                //funciono
                                tareasFragmento tareas = new tareasFragmento();
                                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.qwe, tareas).commit();

                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "La tarea se eliminó correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ocurrió un error en la petición", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }){
                            @Override
                            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
                                return headers;
                            }
                        };
                        queue.add(request);
                        }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No se ha eliminado la tarea", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }

}
```

This is my PUT method in my web Service:

```
 @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    public void put(@PathParam("id")Integer id, Tareas tareas){
        tareas.setId(id);
        try {
            DaoTareas.getInstance().actualizar(tareas);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TareasResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

And finally this is the method where I have my query:

```
@Override
    public void actualizar(Tareas entidad) throws SQLException {
        String query = "UPDATE tareas SET nombre_tarea=?, nota=?, estudiante=? WHERE id = ?";

        if (actualizar == null) {
            actualizar = Conexion.getInstance().getCon().prepareStatement(query);
        }

        actualizar.setString(1, entidad.getNombreUsuario());
        actualizar.setInt(3, entidad.getId());

        actualizar.executeUpdate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add all parameter: `actualizae.setString(2, etidad.getNota())` same with quantity of "?" character.

Comment: If you are in the right ones, do not notice of that error, thank you very much